# @Configurable not working on Subclass

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Take the following general abstract class:

```
@Configurable
    public abstract class TestEntityRoot {
    public abstract String print();
}
```

And a subclass:

```
@Configurable
public class TestEntity extends TestEntityRoot{

    private TestEntityService testEntityService;

    @Autowired
    public void setTestEntityService(TestEntityService testEntityService) {
        this.testEntityService = testEntityService;
    }

    @Override
    public String print() {
        return testEntityService.print();
    }
}
```

When call controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestEntityController {

    @GetMapping(name = "/test")
    public String print() {
        TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
        return entity.print();
    }
}
```

everything ok. But if call like this:

```
@RestController
public class TestEntityController {

    @GetMapping(name = "/test")
    public String print() {
        TestEntityRoot entity = new TestEntity();
        return entity.print();
    }
}
```

i get null pointer. Is it possible that second example work?

Comment: You cannot create Spring beans with caling `new` on bean. Spring needs to process it, to inject beans. Also I see another problem - Don't inject Services into Entities  - it's wrong. Entities should not hold any logic.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case you create manually the class rather than using spring's bean. Autowire the bean instead. See

```
@RestController
public class TestEntityController {
    @Autowired
    private TestEntity entity
    @GetMapping(name = "/test")
    public String print() {
        return entity.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But polimorphism was the main idea. I can have variety of subclasses of TestEntityRoot with different implimintation of method print(). I would like to call it by type TestEntityRoot. But I can't achieve it in AspectJ, and I am not even sure if that is achievable in Spring. May be there is a way that can be done though.

Comment: Use the same approach. Autowire the TestEntityRoot instead.